# Error: After upgrading from xcode 9 to xcode 10.1

Tags: ios, xcode, ipa, xcode10.1

I uploaded a build before one week from xcode 9, it didn't have any problem and was successfully uploaded to the testflight. But I upgraded to Xcode 10 , and now when I upload build then it starts complaining as:

```
 ERROR ITMS-90725: "SDK Version Issue. This app was built with the iOS 
    '${appSDKVersion}' SDK. All iOS apps submitted to the App Store must be built 
    with the iOS '11.0' SDK or later, included in Xcode [9.0] or later. Please 
    update Xcode and rebuild your app."
```

Comment: This link will help you https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=09122018c

Comment: Mahendra GP@ Does this include the deployment target to 12.0 also ?